# Host multiple web application one one server

Tags: spring-boot, http, server, web-applications

I have multiple Java Spring Boot applications that I want to post on internet, but I only have 1 VPS. Is ther any way to host multiple web applications (with different domains for example: one app on example1.domain and other on example2.domain)?
Thanks for your answers

I dont know where to start with, my idea was to route URL to ports different then 80

Answer (score 0):

**Answering the question as I understand, I think you're using AWS cloud**

1. You can host your spring boot application in AWS Beanstalk. here is a [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).
2. Then you can add a custom domain to your Beanstalk application. here is an [tutorial](https://dev.to/bnn1/deploying-dockerized-nextjs-app-to-aws-eb-part-3-setting-custom-domain-45bm).